# Responsive DIVs placement with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, getuikit

I need to place some `DIV`s inside their parent container, no matter if it is the `body`, table's `cell` or another `div`, with [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/), like shown on the attached illustration:

[image]

In case of even number of `DIV`s they should take 50% of the available width placed by 2 at a single line. Or, in case there is odd number of `DIV`s, the last one should take 100% of the available width while all previous still take 50% of the available width and are placed by 2 at a single line.

Preferably with possibility to change the `DIV`s order (like on the Mobile View example).

There is no problem to make this with the [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs) using some simple code like

```
<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-large-1-2">DIV 1 takes 50% of available width</div>
    <div class="uk-width-large-1-2">DIV 2 takes 50% of available width</div>
    <div class="uk-width-large-1-2">DIV 3 takes 100% of available width</div>
</div>
```

But whatever I've searched for with Bootstrap's documentation (as well as Stack Overflow) I still can't find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap is [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts), meaning whatever we define at smaller breakpoints will cascade up to larger breakpoints until overridden.

There are 5 explicit [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints) in addition to the implicit (default) mobile breakpoint:

```
| Breakpoint | Dimensions
|------------|----------- 
| NONE       | <576px
| sm         | ≥576px
| md         | ≥768px
| lg         | ≥992px
| xl         | ≥1200px
| xxl        | ≥1400px
```

---

### To resize the `div`s

Use [columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/) with the responsive breakpoint syntax:

```html
<div class="row g-2">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

- `col-12` specifies full width (12 of 12) at mobile and above
- `col-md-6` specifies half width (6 of 12) at `md` and above (i.e., starting at `md`, this rule overrides the `col-12` rule)
- `g-2` specifies [gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/) to auto-pad the columns (or use manual [spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/) utilities)

Note that the written order (`col-12 col-md-6` vs `col-md-6 col-12`) is irrelevant, as with any css classes. Bootstrap applies the styles in [mobile-first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts) order.

---

### To auto-expand the last `div`

> But what if I don't know how many `div`s are going to be inside the row and therefore do not know if their number would be an odd or an even? Don't know which exact `div` is going to be the last one but still need the last `div` inside the container to be 100% width?

If you are using a templating language, I suggest putting this logic in the template. That's a bit out of scope for this question, but for example with django, a minimal template might look like:

```
<div class="row">
  {% for col in cols %}
  <div class="col-12{% if loop.last and not forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %} col-md-6{% endif %}">
    ...
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Or to handle it with pure css, you could add a `width` rule targeting the last `col` if odd:

```css
.row > .col-md-6:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

### To reorder the `div`s

Use the responsive [flex `order` utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#order):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="order-2 order-md-1">...</div>
  <div class="order-1 order-md-2">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

- `order-2 order-md-1` specifies position 2 at mobile and above, position 1 at `md` and above
- `order-1 order-md-2` specifies position 1 at mobile and above, position 2 at `md` and above

Note that the parent container needs to be a [flex container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/). A bootstrap `row` is flex by default, but for non-flex containers, add the `d-flex` class explicitly.

---

### Minimal example

[image: desktop] [image: mobile]

```css
.row > .col-md-6:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body class="bg-secondary">
  <div class="container pt-3">
    <div class="row g-2">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
        <div class="bg-light text-center p-2">DIV 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <div class="bg-light text-center p-2">DIV 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-3">
        <div class="bg-light text-center p-2">DIV 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-4">
        <div class="bg-light text-center p-2">DIV 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-5">
        <div class="bg-light text-center p-2">DIV 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @tdy Also I should remove `col-md-6` for the last `DIV` in order to make it 100% width. But what if I don't know how many `DIV`s are going to be inside the `row` and therefore do not know if their number would be an odd or an even? Don't know which exact `DIV` is going to be the last one but still need the last `DIV` inside the container to be 100% width

Comment: And one more thing... how to get rid of those default margins? They ruin even your example making the content wider than its container.

Comment: re: odd/even issue, a pure css way is to use `child` selectors to target the last child if odd (answer updated with example). however if you are using a templating language (e.g. jinja, ejs), i would put that logic in the template (i.e., only add `col-md-6` if the last iteration is odd). i added a minimal example of a django template, but beyond that, more in-depth templating issues should probably go in a separate question post.

Comment: re: margins, my original example was just the bare bare minimum to demo the size/order classes. i updated the example to have more spacing (gutters/padding classes).

Comment: @tdy >it sounds like this is being done within some kind of templating language ... No, it is just a number of the news articles which can change during the day.

Comment: @tdy Thanks a lot for explaining each step so detailed. Your solution really works and answers my question, so I've marked it as the answer. But am I the only one who now firmly believes that the Bootstrap's methods are overcomplicated and poorly documented?

Comment: @Pimpfru You're welcome. Re: Bootstrap complexity, it's hard for me to say since (a) I've been using it for a long time and (b) I'm not too familiar with the alternatives. I do remember struggling with the breakpoint syntax until hearing the "mobile first" explanation, which is why I like to mention that. Also when I see your UIKit example (auto-expand the last div), it does look very appealing. In Bootstrap's defense, it was (one of) the first of its kind, so everyone else has had the opportunity to iterate on it.